# How to use loop in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to use a loop in jQuery, but I don't know how to write it.
This is the code I'm going to repeat.

```
$(this).parent().children('span').removeClass('on');
$(this).addClass('on').prevAll('span').addClass('on');
```

I used for at first, but it doesn't work, what should I do?

This is the loop I first wrote.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
   var score = "<%=score%>";
   score = parseFloat(score);
   var count = 0;
   for(i =0; i < Math.round(score); i++) {
     $('.starRev span').parent().children('span').removeClass('on');
     $('.starRev span').addClass('on').prevAll('span').addClass('on');
   }
   return false;
});
```

this is my fullcode

```
 <link href="./CSS/review.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="starRev">
    <span class="starR1"></span>
    <span class="starR2"></span>
    <span class="starR1"></span>
    <span class="starR2"></span>
    <span class="starR1"></span>
    <span class="starR2"></span>
    <span class="starR1"></span>
    <span class="starR2"></span>
    <span class="starR1"></span>
    <span class="starR2"></span>
</div>
```

And this is css

```
 @charset "UTF-8";
 .starR1{
 background: url('http://miuu227.godohosting.com/images/icon/ico_review.png') no-repeat -52px 0;
 background-size: auto 100%;
 width: 15px;
 height: 30px;
 float:left;
 text-indent: -9999px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.starR2{
background: url('http://miuu227.godohosting.com/images/icon/ico_review.png') no-repeat right 0;
background-size: auto 100%;
width: 15px;
height: 30px;
float:left;
text-indent: -9999px;
cursor: pointer;
}
 .starR1.on{background-position:0 0;}
 .starR2.on{background-position:-15px 0;}
```

Comment: You need to fetch the score from the id / class. "<%=score%>" is string.

Comment: <%=score%> is Variable value received from jsp.

Comment: What exactly don't work? the loop not working?

Comment: @OrAssayag This code is repeat it once.

Comment: What is the value of score?

Comment: the value of score is 3.62

Comment: Try running the following code:
$(document).ready( function() {
   var score = 3.62;
   score = Math.round(score);
   var count = 0;
   for(i =0 ; i < score; i++) {
     $('.starRev span').parent().children('span').removeClass('on');
     $('.starRev span').addClass('on').prevAll('span').addClass('on');
   }
});

Comment: Thx, but I Try that code It works over Math.round(score) value

Comment: Please edit your question with the full code, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I dont know what parseFloat is, i guess you wrote it yourself. what I can see is that score, at least in the code you're showing, is a string not a number. Otherwise your code is correct.

Your selectors however are not great. your calling the parent of '.starRev span' which is .starRev. and then selecting the span children again, all of that can be just: `$('.starRev span').removeClass('on')`.

But you're repeting the same code over and over again and is doing the same thing, removing and adding the "on" class. You should review the code inside you for block, i dont think it does what you want. The for block is fine.

Comment: The parseFloat is action to replace String with number. This code is star rating code.